# pywinauto -how to handle alert window control

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have done my form in VB. I cannot access the child window controls. For instance, the alert box appears after submit button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
# used backend="uia"

import sys
import pyautogui
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
print("test")
app=Application().start()
app.Form1.Edit4.type_keys("go")
app.Form1.Edit3.type_keys("12")
app.Form1.Male.click()
app.Form1.ComboBox.type_keys("in")
app.Form1.Edit2.type_keys("33")
app.Form1.Submit.click()
app.Form1.Submit.print_control_identifiers()
app.Success.print_control_identifiers()
app.Form1.Success.click()
```

Success is the name of child window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you write that you've used `backend="uia"` but the code `Application().start()` uses default backend which is `"win32"`. You have to use `Application(backend="uia").start()` to choose "uia".

Note: for "win32" backend the alert window is a top-level window. So you need `app.Success.OK.click()` to click OK button on it. For backend="uia" alert window will be child of "Form1".

EDIT: this code should work:

```
app.Form1.Success.OKButton.click() # alias of .invoke();
# see IsInvokePatternSupported == True in Inspect.exe

# or
app.Form1.Success.OKButton.click_input() # real click
```

EDIT2: It may be timing issue. pywinauto has default timeout 5 seconds waiting for dialog appearance. If dialog appears after more than 5 seconds, you need something like that: `app.Form1.Success.wait('visible', timeout=20)`.

Another possible issue is blocking behavior of `app.Form1.Submit.click()` which calls `InvokePattern`. Sometimes this pattern implementation waits for dialog closing (this is app side issue though). You might have to change this to `app.Form1.Submit.click_input()`.

Comment: actually i have used Application(backend="uia").start() to choose "uia"..and also tried with backend="win32"..even though am not able to click OK button in the Success dialog box...My one doubt is whether it will automatically wait for dialog or i have to manage it..???? NOTE:Am using message box in vb

Comment: OK, can you provide `Inspect.exe` screenshot?

Comment: image 1-https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JZyH.png i image2-https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCzu3.png

Comment: @ vasily Ryabov..Sir any idea ??

Comment: This is pretty easy. 3 levels of window specification is OK for `backend="uia"`. See edited answer.

Comment: No..actually am running as combined scripts...when i run the command separately it is working fine...but as  combined scripts file it is not working..its keep on waiting for the dialog and   fails to click on OKButton in success dialog..Tried click_input() too...No luck!!

Comment: OK, then I need more details. It's not clear what you mean saying "combined scripts file". Please update your question and describe which line fails exactly. And which error output do you have. Maybe application state screenshot would be useful.

If even dialog was not found, it's useless to try `click_input()`. The problem happens before.

Comment: Any more details?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEXNi.png                                                             
 Am running the python script file as child process through npm package...it will open the .exe file and provide inputs on the first page..While clicking submit button the dialog will appear,the script fails in handling the dialog .. i need to close or click OK Button in dialog                                      
NOTE:While checking line by line script via python terminal its perfectly working (ie) am able to handle dialog box .. @Vasily Ryabov

Comment: OK, thanks. It may be timing issue. pywinauto has default timeout 5 seconds waiting for dialog appearance. If dialog appears after more than 5 seconds, you need something like that: `app.Form1.Success.wait('visible', timeout=20)`. Another possible issue is blocking behavior of `app.Form1.Submit.click()` which calls `InvokePattern`. Sometimes this pattern implementation waits for dialog closing (this is app side issue though). You might have to change this to `app.Form1.Submit.click_input()`.

Comment: Cool! Seems the problem is resolved. Please mark the answer as accepted (gray check box under voting buttons at the left side should work for you).